# add_message_files() directory not found:

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm absolute beginner in Ubuntu and ROS. I'm using 12.04 LTS (virtualbox in windows 7) and groovy. I'm using catkin to build my workspace. This is what I did

1- I did create workspace for catkin.

2- I did create "catkin Package".

3- I did build and use catkin package in the workspace.

4- Now I want to use the example WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)

I'm getting the following error

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:64
> (message):   add_message_files()
> directory not found:
> /home/croco/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:8
> (add_message_files)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! Invoking "cmake" failed

I'm sorry I can't post links; however, I'm following the tutorials literally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66392/add_message_files()-directory-not-found:/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial seems to need an update. Please try commenting out the following three lines in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
# add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
# add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
# generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
```

Those are not necessary since this tutorial does not create any custom messages or services.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2013-07-01**:
@Dirk Thomas, Thank you so much. It worked.

**Comment by [Cássio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5385/c%C3%A1ssio/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thank you, It worked.

**Comment by [sina.cb](https://answers.ros.org/users/11966/sina.cb/) on 2014-02-13**:
Thanks a lot!
I was searching for this problem for about 2 hours. You saved my day! :)

**Comment by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on 2017-02-14**:
thank you!